# How to interrupt getResponseCode of the class HttpURLConnection?

Tags: android, http, android-asynctask

I use the class `HttpURLConnection` to send a GET HTTP request, then, I call `getResponseCode` to read the response code. `getResponseCode` is a blocking function, so, I use an `AsyncTask` to execute it in background.
Sometimes, I want to interrupt this function (to drop the pending request and restart a new one, for example).
I thought about calling `cancel()` on the `AsyncTask`. But this does not actually cancel it; Instead, it waits for the background job to be finished before calling the `onCancelled()` callback. So, calling cancel does not help.

I wonder if there is a way to force interrupt the `getResponseCode` function ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to "tell" the server that you do not require their "replies".

According to the [HttpUrlConnection documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html):

> Disconnect. Once the response body has been read, the HttpURLConnection should be closed by calling disconnect(). Disconnecting releases the resources held by a connection so they may be closed or reused.

So you need to call `.disconnect()` to interrupt it.